# Before save flow not running field update on triggered record

Tags: visual-workflow, debugging, sales-cloud

Have a flow with 1 decision element with 4 outcomes to reflect the various Lead Sources I have. For each outcome, I have a field update to the same picklist field. Example If Lead Source is 'B' then update Source to Picklist value 'B'

Issue is that the Lead source B is not updating the field to picklist value 'B' and just showing blank. Criteria for B has 2 conditions:

1. Lead Source = B
   AND
2. Custom text field 'contains' the word 'Download'

When debugging, the record is following the correct lead source path and triggering the field update however when creating a test lead, it is not updating the field.

Can anybody shed some light?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include more details about the flow.  What is the object?  (LeadSource field appears in several objects.)  Is this a record-triggered flow?  Before-save or after-save?

Answer (score 0):

With limited details here, your issue sounds like the Flow is being triggered correctly, but the field update isn't reflecting the expected result. You can try to troubleshoot this in a few different steps:

- Ensure that the picklist field you're trying to update indeed has a value "B". Sometimes, picklists can have values that have a different API name
- Within your Flow, after your decision element, you should have an assignment action that updates the field to the desired picklist value. Double-check this assignment to ensure that it's setting the field to the exact value "B".
- Add a fault connector to your Flow's field update element. This will allow you to capture any errors that might be occurring during the update. You can then use an email alert or some other mechanism to notify you of the error.
- It's possible that another automation, like a workflow rule, process builder, or trigger, is firing after your Flow and modifying the field value. Check if there are other automations on the Lead object that might be affecting the field after your Flow runs.

Hope this helps!